# Wrong persistence.xml read from test project

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, junit, eclipselink

I have a Java SE project that uses EclipseLink. I would like to create an other project for testing my project, and now I'm facing a problem with persistence.xml.

I use eclipse IDE and set up the projects. Both of them has a src folder as Link Source, and the main project is added to the test project's build path. Both src folder has a META-INF subfolder that contains the persistence.xml file. I would like to replace the main project's persistence.xml with the test project's one when running tests. I've tried a lot of options, but it seems the replacing is not persistent... sometimes it works and sometimes it isn't.
(in the test project's persistence.xml I change  tag to a test file.)

I use JUnit4, and when I run a single testcase the replacement seems to be work fine.
But if I try to test a whole test class, then the main project's persistence.xml file is used somehow, and not the test project's one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try:

Make sure the jar of the test project B is before the jar of project A on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Unfortunately, if the project B (test project) is before the project A (main project) on the classpath, then constantly uses the main project's persistent.xml file.